# Bottom Sheet not being shown if hiding keyboard

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

If my keyboard is opened, then on clicking of button if i try to hide my keyboard and change sheetState to show() then my keyboard hides but my sheet is not visible.

***Mimicing opening of sheetState on result from api call.***

***Note - Sheet is shown for first time only***

```
setContent {
        val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
        val key = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
        ModalBottomSheetLayout(
            sheetState = sheetState,
            sheetContent = {
                repeat(20) {
                    Text(text = "$it")
                }
            }
        ) {
            Column {
                var otpResponse by remember { mutableStateOf<Boolean?>(null) }
                if (otpResponse == false) {
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
                        delay(180)
                        otpResponse = true
                    })
                }
                if (otpResponse == true) {
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
                        sheetState.show()
                    })
                }
                Column {
                    var string by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                    TextField(value = string, onValueChange = { string = it })
                    Button(onClick = {
                        key?.hide()
                        otpResponse = false
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "TEST")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There might be issue in other code. I tested your code and it works fine. Like, if i click on test button then keyboard hides and sheet opens.

Comment: @Megh Trying the exact code inside a fragment but its still not working for me

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/102-7VvE4Y_BvHenL6r1eRJ_pM3YR0-vq/view?usp=share_link Can you check this video. Is it the required behaviour?

Comment: @Megh getting desired behviour in emulator at api level 33 not below that

Comment: @Megh Its working in preview, but not inside a fragment

Comment: @sarthakgupta __delay(400)__ seems to work, but we have to look more solid solution!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code have look which is working without delay

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview(){
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    val key = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = sheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            repeat(20) {
                Text(text = "$it")
            }
        }
    ) {
        Column {
            Column {
                var string by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                TextField(value = string, onValueChange = { string = it })
                Button(onClick = {
                    key?.hide()
                    scope.launch{
                        sheetState.show()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text(text = "TEST")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for my colleague to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify previous answer, which is correct, but not clear.

Launch sheetState.show() in a local composition scope (rememberCoroutineScope()), not in LaunchedEffect() scope.